# Flyway 2.1.1 failing to create version table with Oracle

Tags: ant, flyway

I am testing Flyway for the first time, version 2.1.1.
I am using the Ant task `migrate` which should create the `schema_version` table if it does not already exist (and it does not exists in my schema), and I get this error:

```
C:\Users\dmusiani\Desktop\flyaway-test>ant
Buildfile: build.xml

migrate-db:
[flyway:migrate] com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty
 schema "SYSTEM" without metadata table! Use init() first to initialize the meta
data table.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\dmusiani\Desktop\flyaway-test\build.xml:37: Flyway Error: com.googlecod
e.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema "SYSTEM" without metad
ata table! Use init() first to initialize the metadata table.

Total time: 0 seconds
C:\Users\dmusiani\Desktop\flyaway-test>
```

I tried adding the `init` before the migration, and the first time it all works, but as I launch the build a second time, I get an error from the `init` sayng the table already exists.

Here is my Ant target:

```
<target name="migrate-db">

    <path id="flyway.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="./lib">
            <include name="**/flyway*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="flyway.classpath">
        <fileset dir="./lib" includes="ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant"
             resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml"
             classpathref="flyway.lib.path"/>

    <flyway:init  driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:WBMD"
                     user="system"
                     password="manager" 
                     initVersion="0"
                     initDescription="Version table initialization (table &quot;USERNAME&quot;.&quot;schema_version&quot; )"/>

    <flyway:migrate driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:WBMD"
                     user="system"
                     password="manager"
                     sqlMigrationPrefix="patch" >
        <locations>
            <location path="integrations-runtime/HELIOS/1-9-0/nlip-0-5-0/migration/system"/>
        </locations>
    </flyway:migrate>

</target>
```

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: ***NEVER***, ever, under no circumstance run your application with the SYSTEM user. Just don't do it. And never create your own objects in the SYSTEM account. Create a new user with "normal" privileges and use that. Stop using the SYSTEM account for your application.

Comment: I only said I'm using system account right to create other users to use for application ... not to create objects on it nor to use it for application. I appreciate your warning, anyway. Thanks

Comment: Creating users is the job of the DBA, not the responsibility of "the application" and it is definitely not something that should be included in a schema migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to init the db once for Flyway. That is when Flyway creates the table used to track the migrations. As you have noticed, any attempt to init again fails because the table already exists.

I suggest making a separate ant task that calls [Flyway's init](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/ant/init.html) that you can run manually to initialize Flyway, something along the lines of:

```
<target name="init-flyway">

    <path id="flyway.lib.path">
        <fileset dir="./lib">
            <include name="**/flyway*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="flyway.classpath">
        <fileset dir="./lib" includes="ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar"/>
    </path>

    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant"
             resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml"
             classpathref="flyway.lib.path"/>

    <flyway:init  driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                     url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:WBMD"
                     user="system"
                     password="manager" 
                     initVersion="0"
                     initDescription="Version table initialization (table &quot;USERNAME&quot;.&quot;schema_version&quot; )"/>

</target>
```

Comment: This answer is correct for 2.1.1. You will be able to call init multiple times idempotently as of 2.2. However there is another issue, and that is that the table is being created in the schema SYSTEM. You should change it to something else, by either changing the user or setting the schema explicitly using the schemas property.

Comment: Hi, thanks all for replies. About 2.2 I'm looking forward for it, if it improves the behaviour while re-executing init. Meanwhile I will try to manage this somehow in Ant (I cannot go the "manual" way since I have to create an automatic setup wizard ... I think I will use some sql ant task to check if the version table is alredy in place). About the SYSTEM user, the matter is that in my scripts I have to create users and tablespaces, in order to create the DB from scratch; thus I need to use SYSTEM.

Comment: Why in Flyway docs, Ant "migrate" task, is written "Migrates the schema to the latest version. _Flyway will create the metadata table automatically if it doesn't exist_."? It seems not to be true, according to what we wrote in this post ... or am I missing something?

Comment: I know from experience that previous versions of Flyway (<2.2.2) you had to manually trigger the creation of the meta tables. Either the docs are wrong or they have already been updated for 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for 2.2, I have successfully tested (to an oracle DB) the following "automatic" way to initialize Flyway metadata table:

```
<target name="flyway.init.check">
    <!-- Select on the DB to see if the metadata table is already in place-->
    <sql driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:WBMD"
         userid="user"
         password="pwd" 
         print="yes" 
         output="temp.properties"
         expandProperties="true" 
         showheaders="false" 
         showtrailers="false" 
         classpathref="flyway.classpath">
        <![CDATA[
        select 'flyway.metadata.initialized=true' from user_tables where table_name = 'schema_version';
        ]]>
    </sql>
    <!-- load as properies the output from the select -->
    <property file="temp.properties" />
    <delete file="temp.properties" quiet="true"/>
</target>

<target name="flyway.init" depends="flyway.init.check" unless="flyway.metadata.initialized">
    <flyway:init  driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:WBMD"
                 user="user"
                 password="pwd" 
                 initVersion="0"
                 initDescription="Version table initialization"/>
</target>

<target name="migrate-db" depends="flyway.init">
   ......
</target>
```

Enjoy if you like it (maybe using ant-contrib you could get a simpler and more compact solution)

Davide